# How to Show Picture in PictureBox from clicked events in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So i was learning how to use picturebox and its interaction with database, but i pushed my luck and running out of idea.

**So here is my code to open/ load picture from picture box**

```
private void btnopen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "JPEG|*.JPG", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                filename1 = ofd.FileName;
                filename2 = ofd.FileName;

                filename1 = Path.GetFileName(filename1);

                lblfilename.Text =   "/" + filename1 ;
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filename2);
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my SQL queries,

```
 string sql = string.Format("Insert into TB_PRODUCTS (ID,ITEM_name,price,stock,category,picture) Values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')", lblid.Text + txtid.Text, txtdes.Text, txtharga.Text,txtstok.Text,txtkat.Text,  **"Application.StartupPath + "  + lblfilename.Text**);
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Tersimpan", "Pemberitahuan", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            tampil();
```

and here is my datagrid with clicked events

```
 private void DG_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.DG.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            string text1 = row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
            string retString;
            retString = text1.Substring(3);
            txtid.Text = retString;
            txtdes.Text = row.Cells["ITEM_name"].Value.ToString();
            txtharga.Text = row.Cells["price"].Value.ToString();
            txtstok.Text = row.Cells["stock"].Value.ToString();
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(row.Cells["picture"].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

i intend to combine the label from filename for example the filename will become : "/picture.jpg" and when i add the new file it will automatically going to be added just like this : Application.StartupPath + "/Picture.jpg"

but when debugging, and click the datagrid it shows this error :Additional information: Illegal characters in path.

any idea how to show picture apart from this ? thanks and sorry for the messy thread.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using [parameterized queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: check in database table what file name is saved and added here

Comment: use Path.Combine instead of adding manual slashes

Comment: thanks for the path combine solution , but didnt solve the same error tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bizhan advised, you can use Path.Combine Method to connect string. Also I noticed that your code `"Application.StartupPath +"`, maybe you need to remove the double quotes.

After that, you only need to set `lblfilename.Text` to `Picture.jpg` to access the picture.

```
string sql = string.Format("Insert into TB_PRODUCTS (ID,picture) Values('{0}','{1}')", 1, Path.Combine(new string[]{ Application.StartupPath, lblfilename.Text}));
```

Comment: Hi @kyle Wang, your solution is quite useful but i still get an error.

Comment: SOLVED i used full path instead of file name thanks everybody